# Auto increment version number on modified Terraform resource

Tags: terraform

I am creating an aws_imagebuilder_component from a YML file. Everytime I modify the YML, a new version of the component is created, but I have to manually increment the version number to avoid an error. Is there a way to do this automatically, only when the component is indeed modified? I can't really increment it at each run, since the image build takes quite some time.

```
resource "aws_imagebuilder_component" "my_component" {
  data = data.template_file.my_component_file.rendered
  name     = "${var.stage}-myComponent"
  platform = "Windows"
  version  = "1.0.5"
}
```

Comment: You could create a variable for that and change the variable value only. Or maybe do `version = "${major_version}.${minor_version}.${patch_version}"` and define local variables for all three, i.e. `major_version`, `minor_version` and `patch_version`.

Comment: Yes, currently I'm updating the version in place as you suggest (no use for vars, since I don't use this value anywhere else, components can be referenced by x.x.x to always get the latest one). Still, updating the version manually feels like something I should be able to automate with TF. If I manage to find some kind of conditional triggered by a given resource modification, I may have a path to what I want :)

Comment: @RomainPrévost I'm searching with the same question for the exact same reason (more dynamic versioning of `aws_imagebuilder` resources).  I've considered abandoning true semantic versioning and just using `formatdate("YYYY.MM.DD",timestamp())` but that will cause changes every execution. and `ignore_changes` will cause it to never update.

Comment: As an aside, we've completely stopped using imagebuilder, because it was slow as a sleepy turtle when building our Windows images. We're talking twice the time or more as Packer, which we are using since.